# Feedback - Are spaced-repetition cards useful for learning core Dhamma?

Tags: personal-practice, meditation-practicalities, early-buddhism, learning-materials

I've created an Anki deck (still WIP, link here: https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/414202630), drawing on the translations available here in SuttaCentral (with direct links to those pages).  My thinking is that using spaced-repetition might be a helpful way for beginners and intermediate practitioners to grasp the core Dhamma teachings, based on the Early Buddhist texts and extracts (excluding Abhidhamma, later Mahayana teachings, etc., but focusing on the common core across the different traditions.)

Right now, I've just included the Four Truths and the Eightfold Path. This will gradually expand to include the rest of the 37 *bodhipakyadhamma*.

I've also included the Chinese Agama counterparts (but without English translation, so maybe less helpful unless one is bilingual in both English and Traditional Chinese).

My questions:
 1. Do you think such a tool is helpful in learning and practicing the Dhamma? 
 2. Appreciate if you could try out the deck, and provide any feedback for improvement please! :)

With much metta,
PJ

Comment: You might add that people need to [install Anki software](https://apps.ankiweb.net/) to view the flashcards you created. And in fact I won't or I'll tend not to install software I don't know -- I think it's more secure for me (i.e. less likely to corrupt my PC) if the data (e.g. the cards) is distributed/presented as a web application, which I can view in my web browser without installing new software.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you have only a few words on the side of the answer, like https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/87059434.

Currently you have lots of text as the answer and this is detrimental to reading it quickly and memorizing it. So you have to do like the commentators did with their commentaries and their basic lists like here https://suttacentral.net/patthana1.1/en/agganyani

But contrary to them, you would not imagine the lists, you would just copies the words from the suttas. So it would be :

Front   What is the seventh factor of the Eightfold Path?

Back

1. Right mindfulness (Samma sati)
2. ...

then a cateogry for the links, like

Links https://suttacentral.net/sn45.8/en/sujato

Then the detailed sentences in pali & english

Details

1. (Body mindfulness) It’s when a mendicant meditates by observing an aspect of the body—keen, aware, and mindful, rid of desire and aversion for the world.

   - Idha, bhikkhave, bhikkhu kāye kāyānupassī viharati ātāpī sampajāno satimā, vineyya loke abhijjhādomanassaṃ;
2. ...

Comment: Thanks! It's a good point that most Anki cards would have a single answer. And also a good point that categorizing it with "links" and "Details" will aid readability. :)